# Server Side Rendering with React/Redux, getting url params to pass into loadData

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, server-side-rendering

I am pretty positive why this won't work, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

I have a component which uses a `loadData()` function at the end in order to pass data through to the store to be SSR.

An example component would be something like

```
class Test extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div>Test</div>
    )
  }
}

const loadData = store => {
  return store.dispatch(actions.getRecord(this.props.match.params.id));
};

export default {
  component: Test,
  loadData: loadData
}
```

The problem here is that `this.props.match.params.id` is undefined, particularly at the props part. I know this is because I am not inside the component, how do I access the params from the URL inside this?

Just incase this helps I will show my SSR part as well:

```
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { renderRoutes } from 'react-router-config';
import serialize from 'serialize-javascript';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import { matchRoutes } from 'react-router-config';

import routes from './src/routes';
import createStore from './src/stores';

function handleRender(req, res) {
  const store = createStore.configure(null); // create Store in order to get data from redux

  const promises = matchRoutes(routes, req.path)
    .map(({ route }) => {
      // Matches the route and loads data if loadData function is there
      return route.loadData ? route.loadData(store) : null;
    })
    .map(promise => {
      if (promise) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          promise.then(resolve).catch(resolve); // lets all data load even if route fails
        });
      }
    });

  Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    const context = {};
    if (context.url) {
      return res.redirect(301, context.url); // redirect for non auth users
    }

    if (context.notFound) {
      res.status(404); // set status to 404 for unknown route
    }

    const content = renderToString(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <StaticRouter location={req.path} context={context}>
          <div>{renderRoutes(routes)}</div>
        </StaticRouter>
      </Provider>
    );

    const initialState = serialize(store.getState());

    const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic();

    res.render('index', { content, initialState, helmet });
  });
}

module.exports = handleRender;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `match` property within each matchRoutes item, which you can pass into your `loadData` function:

```
matchRoutes(routes, req.path)
    .map(({ route, match }) => {
      return route.loadData ? route.loadData(store, match) : Promise.resolve(null);
    })
```

Your loadData function can then access it:

`const loadData = (store, match) => store.dispatch(reduxAction(match.params.id))`

Comment: I have done this already, but forgot to put the answer haha, thanks for answering this ill accept!